# Как убрать изображение PascalABC.net

Tags: pascalabc.net

Допустим, я вывожу изображение так:

```
uses GraphABC;
begin
  (New Picture('Картинка.jpg')).Draw(0,0);
end.
```

Как его потом убрать? Или заменить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте именованные экземпляры класса, чтобы было проще к ним обращаться. Например, так:

```
uses GraphABC;
var
  pic:Picture;
begin
  pic := Picture.Create('c:\Вашпуть\картинка.jpg'); // создаём экземпляр класса и загружаем из файла изображение 
  pic.Draw(0,0); // размещаем, где надо

    // теперь, при желании:
  pic.Clear; // очищаем изображение
  pic.Load('c:\Вашпуть\картинка1.jpg'); // загружаем иную картинку
  pic.TextOut(10,10,'Моя строка'); // пишем на неё что-либо и так далее
end.
```